# How to get character position when click on text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function to get position of the cursor when you click on the text, it only works for monospace characters which is fine, but it obviously don't work with characters that are wider like Chinese or Japanese ones.

```
    function get_char_pos(point) {
        var prompt_len = self.find('.prompt').text().length;
        var size = get_char_size();
        var width = size.width;
        var height = size.height;
        var offset = self.offset();
        var col = Math.floor((point.x - offset.left) / width);
        var row = Math.floor((point.y - offset.top) / height);
        var lines = get_splited_command_line(command);
        var try_pos;
        if (row > 0 && lines.length > 1) {
            try_pos = col + lines.slice(0, row).reduce(function(sum, line) {
                return sum + line.length;
            }, 0);
        } else {
            try_pos = col - prompt_len;
        }
        // tabs are 4 spaces and newline don't show up in results
        var text = command.replace(/\t/g, '\x00\x00\x00\x00').replace(/\n/, '');
        var before = text.slice(0, try_pos);
        var len = before.replace(/\x00{4}/g, '\t').replace(/\x00+/, '').length;
        return len > command.length ? command.length : len;
    }
```

I've tried to create a function using wcwidth library (that return 2 for wider characters and 1 for normal letters) but it don't work quite right, here is the code with demo:

```js
var self = $('pre');
var offset = self.offset();
var command = 'チトシタテイトチトシイスチトシタテイトチトシイスチトシタテイトチトシイス\nfoo bar baz\nfoo bar baz\nチトシタテイトチトシイ';
self.html(command);
function get_char_size() {
    var span = $('<span>&nbsp;</span>').appendTo(self);
    var rect = span[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    span.remove();
    return rect;
}
var length = wcwidth;
// mock
function get_splited_command_line(string) {
    return string.split('\n');
}
function get_char_pos(point) {
    var size = get_char_size();
    var width = size.width;
    var height = size.height;
    var offset = self.offset();
    var col_count = Math.floor((point.x - offset.left) / width);
    var row = Math.floor((point.y - offset.top) / height);
    var lines = get_splited_command_line(command);
    var line = lines[row];
    var col = 0;
    var i = col_count;
    while (i > 0) {
        i -= length(line[col]);
        col++;
    }
    var try_pos;
    if (row > 0 && lines.length > 1) {
        try_pos = col + lines.slice(0, row).reduce(function(sum, line) {
            return sum + length(line);
        }, 0);
    } else {
        try_pos = col;
    }
    // tabs are 4 spaces and newline don't show up in results
    var text = command.replace(/\t/g, '\x00\x00\x00\x00').replace(/\n/, '');
    var before = text.slice(0, try_pos);
    var len = before.replace(/\x00{4}/g, '\t').replace(/\x00+/, '').length;
    var command_len = command.length;
    return len > command_len ? command_len : len;
}
self.click(function(e) {
  var pos = get_char_pos({
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
  });
  self.html(command.substring(0, pos-1) + '<span>' +
            command[pos] + '</span>' +
            command.substring(pos+1));
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jcubic/leash/master/lib/wcwidth.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

I can't use spans for each letter because I have the text split into 3 spans before, cursor and after the cursor. and I also have spans for styling that may be or not in the container.

Any help how to fix this function is appreciated.

**SOLUTION**:

Here is my code based on @Will that I've used in my code that work with multiple elements (for some reason chrome have issues when you click on element that have only one character, and just in case the focus is not more then the length of the text):

```
    function get_focus_offset() {
        var sel;
        if ((sel = window.getSelection()) && (sel.focusNode !== null)) {
            return sel.focusOffset;
        }
    }
    function get_char_pos(e) {
        var focus = get_focus_offset();
        if ($.isNumeric(focus)) {
            var node = $(e.target);
            // [role="presentation"] is my direct children that have
            // siblings that are other nodes with text
            var parent = node.closest('[role="presentation"]');
            var len = node.text().length;
            focus = len === 1 ? 0 : Math.min(focus, len);
            return focus + parent.prevUntil('.prompt').text_length() +
                node.prevAll().text_length();
        } else {
            return command.length;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**: there is issue with clicking if you click on the first half the character it get selected correctly but when you click other half it select next character so I ended up with one character per element approach.

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: How many characters are you looking at? Would it be feasible to wrap each one in its own span?

Comment: @charlietfl I need this for jQuery Terminal to move the cursor on click. I already have this working but it don't work for wider characters.

Comment: @J.Chen it will be hard because I need to have also spans with colors and style in container and will be hard to distinguish span that have style with span that is letter.

Comment: By the way, do you need to get any information about character stylings ?(color, size, weight etc..)

Comment: @Tamango no, just the position so I can change the cursor, text before and text after.

Comment: In 2024, I would point to the `document.caretPositionFromPoint()` method as a solution to this. In WebKit-derived browsers there is `document.caretRangeFromPoint()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.charPosition').forEach(el => {
        let characters = el['innerText'].split('');
        el.innerHTML = '';
        characters.forEach(char => {
            let span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerText = char;
            span.addEventListener('click', function () {
                let position = 0;
                let el = this;
                while (el.previousSibling !== null) {
                    position++;
                    el = el.previousSibling;
                }
                console.log(this.innerHTML + ':' + position);
            });
            el.appendChild(span);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="charPosition">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution, but I can't use spans because I maybe have spans in my container that have styling and also I have the text split into two parts divided by cursor, sorry didn't mention that.

Comment: I've ended up with this solution after all.

Answer (score 5):

Third attempt. Stuff a pipe character in there to pretend to be a cursor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
document.querySelectorAll('.charPosition').forEach(el => {
    let clean, cursor;
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let position = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
        if (cursor && position > cursor)
            position--;
        if (clean)
            el['innerText'] = clean;
        let textnode = el.firstChild['splitText'](position);
        clean = textnode.wholeText;
        cursor = position;
        el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('|'), textnode);
        el['innerText'] = textnode.wholeText;
    });
});
});
```

```html
<div class="charPosition">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Comment: It wasn't me, maybe because you've added 2 answers.

Comment: Do you know cross-browser solution for `focusOffset`?

Comment: I added a second answer because the first one had some upvotes and it seemed weird to change message that they already upvoted. Oh well. The Selection API has pretty broad support. https://caniuse.com/#feat=selection-api There are some polyfills out there for IE8, etc.

Comment: You're second solution with focusOffset is exactly what I need, thanks. Found this gist with cross-browser for focusOffset https://gist.github.com/tcr/1022198

Comment: But looking at can I use it seems that I don't need IE8 so just focusOffset is fine, thanks again.