# Read character on mouse select

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to read the text from particular position some where with in the div.

eg:

```
<div>Click ME I am here</div>
```

When I draw a rectangle over a text it should read the text behind the rectangle. Just like selecting the text. But not in the same way.
For example
in this image **text** should be displayed.
[image]

Comment: You can do it with simple traversal. Here is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333785/6523658).