# How can I insert a fake caret onto a div/span that contains text?

Tags: javascript, css, editor

Google Docs uses a tiny div as a caret for editing text. If I have just a div with some text on it that is not using `contenteditable`, such as this:

`<div id="some-text">This is some text.</div>`

How could I set a fake caret on it?

So far these have been my approaches:

- On click, get the real caret's location and set the fake caret to that location. The problem here is that it's not an editable div so there isn't a real caret and I don't think this is possible even with a real caret.
- Somehow find the closest text node, get the width of the text node to the position, then place the cursor. This solution is completely over my head on how to achieve it.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean you want to place a caret (small triangle) wherever the user clicks?

Comment: @Jasonbamber I'm talking about the text caret that blinks to indicate where you're going to type.

Comment: Ok, i understand what character you mean. Now, where do you want to place it? at the position the user clicks?

Comment: @Jasonbamber Yeah. I know how to place it at the exact position the user clicks, but it needs to be inline with the text. For example, if I click on the middle of the "o" in "some", the div would go to the area between the "o" and the "m".

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332637/how-to-get-character-position-when-click-on-text-in-javascript/45333785 Check out the live snippet in the selected answer